# Como configuar a validação do cliente no em uma aplicação ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0 para reconhecer padrão pt-BR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, asp.net-core

Eu estou com dificuldades para configurar a validação do lado do cliente dom meu aplicativo. Eu gostaria que a validação do cliente, usando `jquery.validate.unobstrusive`, aceitasse números e datas localizados em pt-BR.

Eu já fiz essa configuração no método `startup` da aplicação

```
var locale = "pt-BR";
RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions {
    SupportedCultures   = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(locale)
};
```

e adicionei `<html lang="pt-br">` no arquivo HTML principal.

Acontece que funcionou direitinho para renderizar números e datas do lado do servidor, mas a validação do lado do cliente ainda está esperando inputs em  `en-US`.

Como eu posso configurar a aplicação Asp.NET Core MVC 2.0 para aceitar números e datas em `pt-BR` do lado do cliente?